# Gradle: how to make static resources available on the classpath of same project's module

Tags: java, spring, gradle, resources, classpath

How can I have the api-module resources' content available on the classpath of whatever module is depending from api-module? core-module can't be a bootable jar nor they can be grouped together.

I have the following project structure in Gradle:

```
main-module/
├── api-module/
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── resources/
│       ├── api_definition.yaml
├── core-module/
│   ├── build.gradle
```

And this is
core-module/build.gradle:

```
 ...
dependencies {
  implementation project(":api-module")
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

By convention, Gradle assumes that production resources are placed into the `src/main/resources` directory ([Java Plugin Project Layout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout)).

Move `api_definition.yaml` to `src/main/resources` underneath project `api-module` and it'll be available on the classpath of `core-module`.